# Find image in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
       Image  Id
0     1a.jpg  w_1
1     c4.jpg  w_1
2     b01.jpg w_2
3     d5.jpg  w_1
4     df.jpg  w_f
5     c2.jpg  w_2
6     ab.jpg  w_3e
```

What is the pandas way to return this output?

```
output:(1a.jpg,c4.jpg,d5.jpg)(b01.jpg,c2.jpg)(df.jpg)(ab.jpg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and convert values to `tuple`s first and then to `list`:

```
L = df.groupby('Id', sort=False)['Image'].apply(tuple).tolist()
print (L)
[('1a.jpg', 'c4.jpg', 'd5.jpg'), ('b01.jpg', 'c2.jpg'), ('df.jpg',), ('ab.jpg',)]
```

Similar for convert to `list`s instead `tuple`s:

```
L1 = df.groupby('Id', sort=False)['Image'].apply(list).tolist()
print (L1)
[['1a.jpg', 'c4.jpg', 'd5.jpg'], ['b01.jpg', 'c2.jpg'], ['df.jpg'], ['ab.jpg']]
```

And if need `string`s:

```
s = ''.join('(' + df.groupby('Id', sort=False)['Image'].apply(', '.join) +')')
print (s)
(1a.jpg, c4.jpg, d5.jpg)(b01.jpg, c2.jpg)(df.jpg)(ab.jpg)
```